# Using Pil, exif to save multiple images according to their position

Tags: python, loops, python-imaging-library, coordinates, exif

I have a large set of photos that when stitched together constitute a map . I need to write a small code that goes through the images, reads the coordinates( latitude, longitude ) and saves them in four files.

[photo that expalins how I want the 1000 photo (1 map) to be saved in four files according to their location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybIYH.jpg)

I was able to figure out how to read a single image coordinates using python

```
pip install exif

from exif import Image
img_path = 'images/image_exif.jpg'
with open(img_path, 'rb') as src:              # open(filename, mode).
    img = Image(src)
    print (src.name, img)

import PIL
from PIL import Image
image = PIL.Image.open('images/image_exif.jpg')


img.gps_longitude
```

so what I want to do now, is itterate through all the images to find the the two axes and then find which images lay in the first quarter, save them in a file, which in the second, save them in another file.....etc

I tried to find the highest long and lat, so that then I find the min long and lat, in order to find the midpoint

source_path = r"C:\Users\q\Pictures\Test"

```
for i in source_path:
    max(i.gps_longitude)
```

But I got the following error : str' object has no attribute 'gps_longitude'

Comment: Please: include the images in the question, not with random links. Links expires! `folder_path` is not defined in your code, so we cannot really help. Note: you are also using max of the same quantity twice, and you are not storing the results.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You say you have a large collection of images that make a map, then you show an example with 4 images. So do you mean your large collection of photos, say 1000, makes 250 maps with 4 images each? Or do you mean your 1000 photos make a single map with 250 tiles? You say you want to create 4 files. What's in each file? Is each file an image? Or a list of image names? Or a list of coordinates?

Comment: @MarkSetchell  sorry about the confusion. say I have 1000 photos(1 map), those 1000 when matched and loaded through a map-analysis software, the software can put them together and prepare them for me to start performing different functions. now; I don't want to load the 1000 because my PC isn't that powerful. I want to take a section of the map  ( 1 quarter of the map for example which will be 250 photos) and save it in a file so that I can work on each section separately.

Comment: @MarkSetchell the image I showed is to explain how I want the 1000 images(1 map)  to be saved in four files.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi sorry about the confusion. I fixed the errors you pointed to me.

Comment: Try checking your files with `exiftool` first like this `exiftool -filename -gpslatitude -gpslongitude -T *.jpg`

Comment: I realise there may be other concerns/constraints, but it's often simpler to split images into 4 long, full-width horizontal strips rather than worrying about 2 axes and also they are more naturally contiguous in memory that way than in quadrants. Just saying 

Comment: `source_path` is a string, and you loop for every character, not images or files in the folder/directory with the name of your string.